# Problems making an intent with action [server for php - android app]

Tags: java, android, android-intent

i am using the App [Server For PHP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.esminis.server.php) for android.

In the last update the app permit make intents for Stop, start and others. 
[Here the class](https://bitbucket.org/esminis/server/src/cc9cf3d7e9e855baaaf6dd6b23a813f5e60ec2f4/Library/src/main/java/com/esminis/server/library/activity/external/IntentAction.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)

When i try access by the intent, return me a error **"No Activity found to handle intent {act=STOP}"**

The instruction inside the class are:

```
/**
 * External intent action information class
 *
 * Here you will find:
 * ACTION_* - supported intent actions
 * ERROR_* - error codes with description
 * FIELD_* - intent data fields
 *
 * Intent sending works this way:
 * #1 you send intent with supported action and server package name
 * #2 user sees dialog asking if he allows your application to execute action for your application
 * #3 if user allows action, then action progress dialog will be shown
 * #4 you get call to your onActivityResult, with resultCode and sometimes data intent. resultCode
 * will be Activity.RESULT_OK or error code
 *
 * @see IntentActionRequest - it is helper class for sending external intents
 */
```

my code in the **MainActivity.java** is:

```
package com.itdep.lact.restartserverphp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn;
    Context c = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent server = new Intent("com.esminis.server.php");
                if (server.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null ){
                    //Toast.makeText(c.getApplicationContext(), server.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startActivityForResult(server, 0);
                }
                try {
                    server.setAction("STOP");
                    c.startActivity(server);
                    Toast.makeText(c.getApplicationContext(), "Good", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(c.getApplicationContext(), "error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });



    }
}
```

Here my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.itdep.lact.restartserverphp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.esminis.server.php"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

best regards.

Comment: are you sure `setAction("STOP")` is not `setAction(ACTION_STOP)`?

Comment: i tried with both and the same problem :(